# Twilio Conversations - Get Maximum call stack size exceeded on React Native

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-conversations

I'm trying to use [twilio conversations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@twilio/conversations) from javascript in React Native.

I'm getting RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (native stack depth) when calling

```
const Conversations = require('@twilio/conversations');

Conversations.Client.create(token)
```

My package.json looks like

```
{
    "@twilio/conversations": "^1.2.2",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-navigation": "^7.16.0",
    "react-native-navigation-hooks": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-twilio-video-webrtc": "https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc",
    "react-stomp": "^5.1.0",
  }
```

Here is the [logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mm-jKYDtnDfwkhB3_MByb6ASkTiWKKRh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: provide more info about the error or code of the conponent

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit this is the only error I'm getting from the console. Just calling the create() method will trigger the error so what are the other information you would like?

Comment: The information you have provided is unclear to understand and solve your issue.

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit Just import the module will create the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Can you try importing the module with `import` instead of `require`? Like:

```js
import {Client} from '@twilio/conversations';
```

Then you can see more debug information from the client if you change the `logLevel` when you create it:

```js
Client.create(token, { logLevel: 'debug' });
```

Comment: Thanks for checking me out. I have added the logs file.

Comment: I can't reproduce the `RangeError`. Your logs also show that the conversations SDK is connecting successfully. When I searched for the error string, I found [this report](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/135) that mentions including a large JSON file. Do you include any large files that require parsing as part of your application?

Comment: No, I do not include any large file. I agree that SDK is connecting successfully; however, without calling it will create no issue. I also use conversations as a combination with twilio video "react-native-twilio-video-webrtc".

Is there any way I can check whether there is a large file is being parsed?

Comment: create() function also never returns me back the instance of chat client including no error message in try/catch

Comment: do you have any speculation which I can start digging in

Comment: `create` is asynchronous and returns a Promise that resolves to a client, not an instance of a client.

Comment: Could there be some issue with getting the bundler to install from GitHub? Can you just include `react-native-twilio-video-webrtc` version 2.0 from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc)?

Comment: I managed to make it works by include "inlineRequires: false" in my metro.config.js

Thanks for your supports.

Comment: Oh cool! Glad to hear something worked out!

Comment: @TuySotheara could you please update the accepted answer? your solution is hidden in the comment-dropdown.